# Can I call a library function from web3.py?

Tags: solidity, web3.py, python

I first deploy the following library.

```
library Array {
    function remove(uint[] storage arr, uint index) public {
        // Move the last element into the place to delete
        require(arr.length > 0, "Can't remove from empty array");
        arr[index] = arr[arr.length - 1];
        arr.pop();
    }
}
```

Next, I create a contract where I use the above defined library.

```
contract TestArray {
    using Array for uint[];

    uint[] public arr;

    function testArrayRemove() public {
        for (uint i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            arr.push(i);
        }

        arr.remove(1); // replicate this function call in web3.py?

        assert(arr.length == 2);
        assert(arr[0] == 0);
        assert(arr[1] == 2);
    }
}
```

I can read the data from arr state variable using `web3.functions.arr().call()`, however can I call the remove function directly from web3.py?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can, as long as the `remove` function is public and the function calling `remove` is also public in the contract. By the way, you need an additional parameter when calling `remove` in `arr.remove(1)` as `remove` takes two parameters as you defined it in the library.

Comment: Can you help me with the syntax of calling remove directly from web3.py? I have tried web3.functions.arr().remove(i), but it gives me error. 
On second point, that is the syntax for using libraries in solidity. Reference: https://solidity-by-example.org/library/